# How to pass value from a button to a controller method in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, crud, delete-record

I working on a simple laravel 5.2 application. I want to pass a value `$id` from the view when a button is clicked to the controller method `destroy()`. This is what i have tried:
This is my route

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', array('as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'ContactsController@destroy'));
```

... and this is my button in a view:

```
<a href="{{ action('ContactsController@destroy/{$contacts->id}/') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

But this code didn't work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Using `get()` method to delete is a very bad idea. This is insecure.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls) you should be able to do this:

```
 {{ action('ContactsController@destroy', ['id' => $contacts->id]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route is expecting an id so you don't need to pass an identifier. The below code should work for you.

Make sure you're using the correct brackets as by default in Laravel 5.2 you'll need to use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}.

```
<a href="{{ route('delete', $contacts->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a GET request, you can simply have you own href instead of using blade. I just find this more readable:

```
<a href="/delete/{{$contacts->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```